# Django Reportlab generates empty pdf

Tags: python, django, pdf, reportlab

I'm using reportlab to create a pdf. I am using Reportlab Paragraphs. The problem is everytime i download it, it generates an empty txt.
I tested it without django and it works without a problem. If i'm using canvas it works but it doesn't suit what i need.

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter


def genereaza_pdf(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="example.pdf"'
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate("example.pdf", pagesize=letter, rightMargin=70, leftMargin=70, topMargin=70,
                                bottomMargin=60)
        report = []

        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name="Times", fontName='Times-Roman', fontSize=15, alignment=TA_JUSTIFY))

        p_text = "<u>ANEXA 1</u>"
        report.append(Paragraph(p_text, styles["Times"]))
        report.append(Spacer(1, 5))
        doc.build(report)
        return response
    return render(request, 'pdf_test.html')
```

pdf_test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Download pdf</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit">Download</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function was generating two files, one in Downloads as default but it was an empty txt and one in the project's directory. I've made the changes.

```
def genereaza_pdf(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="example.pdf"'
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate(response, pagesize=letter, rightMargin=70, leftMargin=70, topMargin=70,
                                bottomMargin=60)
        report = []

        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name="Times", fontName='Times-Roman', fontSize=15, alignment=TA_JUSTIFY))

        p_text = "<u>ANEXA 1</u>"
        report.append(Paragraph(p_text, styles["Times"]))
        report.append(Spacer(1, 5))
        doc.build(report)
        return response
    return render(request, 'pdf_test.html')
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to write the file to stream. Try this:

```
from io import BytesIO
def genereaza_pdf(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="example.pdf"'
        buff = BytesIO()
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buff, pagesize=letter, rightMargin=70, leftMargin=70, topMargin=70,
                                bottomMargin=60)
        report = []

        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name="Times", fontName='Times-Roman', fontSize=15, alignment=TA_JUSTIFY))

        p_text = "<u>ANEXA 1</u>"
        report.append(Paragraph(p_text, styles["Times"]))
        report.append(Spacer(1, 5))
        doc.build(report)
        response.write(buff.getvalue())
        buff.close()
        return response
    return render(request, 'pdf_test.html')
```